# Accessing data.table with vector of colnames inside function

Tags: r, function, scope, data.table, multiple-columns

I get the error `"Error in myData$ID1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"` in trying to get *Correct output* by using the function below. For some reason, the function does not get the column names inherited and hence getting the error `invalid for atomic vectors`.

**So how to get the colnames correctly inherited and how to fix this error?**

```
#HOW TO DO THIS WITH apply below?
myData <- data.table(ID1=c("1;11","2;22","3;33"),ID2=c("a;b","c;d",";"))

readMyRow <- function(myData, myIndex)
{
    #TODO: Error is here because col names not inherited, why?
    s3<- strsplit(myData$`ID1`, split=";")  
    s4<- strsplit(myData$`ID2`, split=";")  
    return(paste(s3[[myIndex]], s4[[myIndex]], sep=";"))
}

#Combine all rows  
myData$Combined <- apply(myData, 1, readMyRow)
```

*CORRECT OUTPUT*

```
myData <- data.table(ID1=c("1;11","2;22","3;33"),ID2=c("a;b","c;d",";"))
s3<- strsplit(myData$`ID1`, split=";")  
s4<- strsplit(myData$`ID2`, split=";")  
paste(s3[[1]], s4[[1]], sep=";")
paste(s3[[2]], s4[[2]], sep=";")
paste(s3[[3]], s4[[3]], sep=";")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** the rows turn into vectors, you need to handle them accordingly.

Setup:

```
myData <- data.table(ID1=c("1;11","2;22","3;33"),ID2=c("a;b","c;d",";"))

readMyRow <- function(myData, myIndex)
{
    #TODO: Error is here because col names not inherited, why?
    s3<- strsplit(myData$`ID1`, split=";")  
    s4<- strsplit(myData$`ID2`, split=";")  
    return(paste(s3[[myIndex]], s4[[myIndex]], sep=";"))
}
```

If we `debug(readMyRow)` and then `apply(myData,1,readMyRow)`, get into the function, and then do `str()`, we see that the row has been reduced to a character vector.

```
str(myData)
Named chr [1:2] "1;11" "a;b"
- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "ID1" "ID2")
```

The `$` accessor doesn't work on atomic vectors, but `[[` will:

```
readMyRow <- function(myData, myIndex=1) {
   s3 <- strsplit(myData[["ID1"]], split=";")  
   s4 <- strsplit(myData[["ID2"]], split=";")  
  return(paste(s3[[myIndex]], s4[[myIndex]], sep=";"))
}
```

(I also added a default value for `myIndex`: otherwise the function doesn't work without an index specified.)

```
apply(myData,1,readMyRow)
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3] 
[1,] "1;a"  "2;c"  "3;" 
[2,] "11;b" "22;d" "33;"
```